# Send and populate email through a button in Quickbase

Tags: email, url, quickbase

I am new to the community and would love to implement a button in my DEAL table where it sends out an email (i want it to prompt my outlook window) to the email linked to a different table, CONTACTS and auto-record the content that is being sent into a different table, say EMAIL.

I have created a button already like below: in the URL section of my button.

```
"mailto:"&""&[email]&"\n"&"?subject="&"\n"&[Subject]&""&"&body="&[Body]&""
```

where [email] is where i want to grab the mail
and [subject] and [body] are my predefined fields in the same table

but I don't know how to
1) grab the email address that is being stored in a different table
2) save the content that was sent out attached by an ID that is the same ID as deal
Additional Questions:
3) Would it be possible to track the sender's and receivers email conversation beyond just the initial "send"?
4) Are there any other third party software than can do this for me?

Comment: For 3, as far as I know, the answer is generally no, unless your IT department has a mail server that would allow you to webhook/query for the emails.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you would want to do is create a relationship between those two tables where CONTACTS is a parent table to DEALS. Then you can create a Lookup field on the DEALS table that passes the value of the email address to the DEALS table. I included a couple screen shots of how this would look in Quick Base.
[image]

[image]

There are third party add-ons for Quick Base that can help you track conversations, etc. Here's an example: https://www.juicedtech.com/email-parser